# how to implement the builtin set in Python with list comprehension

Tags: python, set

how can I implement the *unique* function below with a list comprehension? I don't want to use the builtin *set* for the order of elements in set is arbitrary

```
def unique(list):
    u = []
    for e in list:
        if e not in u:
            u.append(e)
    return u
```

Comment: Is just `set` that you can't use , or any other built ins are forbidden  too?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, not like this, because you need to keep track of seen elements at each iteration, which isn't something you can do with that syntax. The pythonic method of uniquifying a list with order is using an `OrderedDict` (or just a dict with python3.7+).

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> [k for k in OrderedDict.fromkeys([1, 2, 1, 3])]
[1, 2, 3]
```

You don't actually need the list comprehension.

```
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([1, 2, 1, 3]))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3.6 you can use a dict to emulate an ordered set:

```
def unique(l):
    return list(dict(zip(l, l)))
print(unique([3, 2, 4, 2]))
```

This outputs:

```
[3, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Dicts being ordered is only a official feature since python 3.7. In 3.6 it's nothing more than a CPython implementation detail.

Comment: How do you think of this one below?

`def uniq(l):
    u = []
    d = [u.append(e) for e in l  if e not in u]
    return u
`

Comment: @SamD. You shouldn't use list comprehension for side effects. Just use a regular `for` loop in this case.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to sort the `set` by the index of the element is the list `l`:

```
def unique(l):
    return list(sorted(set(l),key=l.index))
print(unique([1,2,3,3]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It was never mentioned that the list should be returned in sorted order. What if the list is [2, 1, 1, 3]? The answer is [2, 1, 3], not [1, 2, 3]. This is wrong.

Comment: @coldspeed Okay, but i realized that my code produces same output ([2,1,3]) as yours, what's the problem

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see the `l.index`. However, using `index` as the key makes this O(N ** 2 log N), which is inefficient...

Comment: @coldspeed Ah thanks for letting me know, You've got the best solution here

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you!

I tried to implement it as following:

```
def uniq(list):
    u = []
    d = [u.append(e) for e in list  if e not in u]
    return u
```

Although it works as expected, it might be a bad code practice in some sense (I am a newbie in Python)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```py
def unique(list):
    u = []
    return list(set([e for e in list if e not in u]))

print(unique(["1", 1, "1", 2]))
```

output:

```
[1, 2, '1']
```